# Scroller isn't displaying on the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having an issue with the position-fix; top 100px;. when I use position-fix; top 100px; and run the program, the result will be "google scroller doesn't show up on the screen". when I don't use when I use position-fix; top 100px; then google scroller shows up on the screen.

Here is the HTML code.

```
<body>
  <section class="container">
    <div style="position:fixed; top:180px" class="First">
      <ul id="ListName" class="">
        <li><a style="text-decoration:none" href="interest.html"> Interest </a></li>
      </ul>     
    </div>


    <div style="position:fixed; top:180px;" class="Second">
      <h1  align="center"> sport</h1>

         <p>

          <ul>
            <li> soccer and,</li>
            <li> football </li>
          </ul>

        </p>

   </div>
 </section>

 <div id="" class="" style="clear:both;"></div>
</body>
```

Here is the CSS code.

```
<style>
        .container {
            width: 99%;
            height: auto;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 10px;
            font-family: Verdana,Geneva,Tahoma,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif!important;
        }
        .First {
            height: auto;
            width: 20%;
            background: white;
            border:1px solid #666;
            float: left;
        }
        .Second {
            margin-left: 21%;
            height: auto;
            width:640px;
            border:1px solid #666;
            background: white;
        }



</style>
```

Comment: What is your requirement here? You want the scrollbar to be visible ? Your question is not clear.

Comment: Yes, I want the scroller

Comment: If the content inside div overflows then only scroll bar will appear. You have to set a height value like height:100px;  and overflow:visible;

Comment: Scroll bar appeared but when I scroll the bar, it doesn't scroll the page

Comment: You want to scroll the whole body or just the div?

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply, I want to scroll the whole body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement is bit confusing, it's not clear that whether you want to make the second div inside the section element scrollable then you can do it by adding a height or max-height property to the Second class.

Same holds true for any container scroll bar appear only when the content inside a div or any container exceeds the height specified.

If you want to make second div scrollable, you need to do following.

```
   .Second {
      height:100px !important;
      overflow-y: scroll !important;
      margin-left: 21%;
      height: auto;
      width: 640px;
      border: 1px solid #666;
      background: white;
   }
```

If you want to make body element scrollable then you can set a height property or when your content increases the automatically body will be scrollable.

checkout the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/z9dmr7ns/).

I have added a width property to the second div in order to make it fit in the fiddle window.You may remove it. Also pasted some sample text inside body to demonstrate that body is scrollable when it has enough text or if you want a set a fix height you can do that as well.

NOTE: you need to set the property value with !important so that it overrides and forces browser to apply that css.

```
height:100px !important;
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. By the way, I did another way and it is working.

Comment: Nice! You can also answer to your question, this might be helpful to others.